# Can reverse iterator be used as normal iterator?

Tags: c++, iterator

Is something wrong with erasing with reverse iterator? When compiling the code fragment below, I receive 'no matching function' error when using 'rit' as argument for `erase()`.

```
std::vector<MyRecord*>* BLV = GetVector;

for (std::vector<MyRecord*>::iterator it = BLV->begin(); it != BLV->end(); ++it)
  BLV->erase(it);
for (std::vector<MyRecord*>::reverse_iterator rit = BLV->rbegin(); rit != BLV->rend(); ++rit)
  BLV->erase(rit);
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] so not everyone reading your question has to do it over and over again.

Comment: @nwp I only asked 'What is wrong', which I guessed needs only careful reading, rather than running an MWE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed `erase` cannot be used directly with a reverse iterator; you'd essentially be removing the wrong element if it were allowed.

You need to convert `rit` to a forward iterator.

`(rit + 1).base();` will give you the equivalent `it`. Note carefully the `+ 1`.

Putting this together, write

`BLV->erase((rit + 1).base());`

in your reverse case.

Comment: Thank you. It would be worth to build it into the library, I guess.